# Python - how can change the output from a tuple

Tags: python, string

Here is my output:
('TOMŠIČEVA ULICA 4,\n2380 SLOVENJ GRADEC',)
<class 'tuple'>

And this is the output i want: TOMŠIČEVA ULICA 4, 2380 SLOVENJ GRADEC

So i want to get rid of this characters: )(' and \n

Comment: The existing and desired outputs appear identical, make sure you've formatted them correctly. You'll also need to include more details. What have you tried so far? What are `a` and `b`?

Comment: a and b are words in a string for example a is car and b is plane, they are both in the same string

Comment: Look into string replacement with the newline (`\n`) character

Comment: i don't understand what do you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do it, is by concatenating them together

```
a = 'the first string, '
b = 'the second string'
print(a + b)
```

However, you have to put a space at the end of 'a' (and a comma).

So to do it in a nicer way, you can just use the .join() function

```
a = 'the first string'
b = 'the second string'
c = ", ".join([a, b])
```

or instead of adding a variable 'c', just use a print

```
print(", ".join([a, b]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using join function and tuples:

```
a = 'the first string,'
b= 'the second string'
output = (a, b)
result = " ".join(output)
print(result)
```

[watch this code in action](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=a%20%3D%20%27the%20first%20string,%27%0Ab%3D%20%27the%20second%20string%27%0Aoutput%20%3D%20%28a,%20b%29%0Aresult%20%3D%20%22%20%22.join%28output%29%0Aprint%28result%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)